# Can I use a state value to reference a value inside of a lookup table that is stored locally in my project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an API response that contains an item hash. I want to be able to cross reference that item hash with a lookup table that is stored locally in my project, so I am able to display a name and icon path of the item that matches the hash.

I have tried storing the item hash in state and tried to reference it in my render function like so `const weaponURL = hashdata[{weapon}.displayProperties.icon];`. I'm getting an error saying the `Cannot read property 'icon' of undefined`.

I have also tried to reference the icon path using this code in render `{baseURL + {weapon && hashdata[weapon].displayProperties.icon}}` but I get an error from my IDE to say that `: is expected`

Here is my entire JS file:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import hashdata from '../data/data';
import ReactTooltip from 'react-tooltip';
import apiKey from '../data/apiKey';


class XUR extends Component {
    state = {
        isLoading: false,
        error: null,
        xurInventory: null,
        weapon: null,
        gear1: null,
        gear2: null,
        gear3: null
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            isLoading: true
        });

        try {
            const xurFetch = await fetch('https://www.bungie.net/Platform/Destiny2/Vendors/?components=402', {
                headers: {
                    'X-API-KEY': apiKey
                }
            });
            if (!xurFetch.ok) {
                throw Error(xurFetch.statusText);
            }
            const xurInvJson = await xurFetch.json();
            this.setState({
                xurInventory: xurInvJson,
                weapon: xurInvJson.Response.sales.items.data[2190858386].saleItems[54].itemHash,
                isLoading: false
            });
        } catch (error) {
            this.setState({error: true});
        }

    }

    render() {
        const {isLoading, error, weapon} = this.state;
        const baseURL = 'https://www.bungie.net';
        const weaponURL = hashdata[{weapon}.displayProperties.icon];

        if (isLoading) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <p>LOADING</p>
                </div>
            )
        }

        if (error) {
            return(
                <div>
                    <p>Error</p>
                </div>
            )
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <div className={"row justify-content-center"}>
                    <div className={"col-6 text-center py-2"}>
                        <img alt="icon" src={baseURL + {weapon && hashdata[weapon].displayProperties.icon}}/>
                        <ReactTooltip/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default XUR;
```

Here is a snippet from my data hash file:

```
const hashdata = {
    "31953744": {
        "displayProperties": {
            "description": "",
            "name": "Holy Ground",
            "icon": "/common/destiny2_content/icons/d76ab9a89d00451c6a0c1d779a3e5f98.jpg",
            "hasIcon": true
        },
        "scope": 1,
        "sourceString": "Source: Complete activities and earn rank-up packages on Io.",
        "sourceHash": 315474873,
        "itemHash": 31953744,
        "acquisitionInfo": {
            "runOnlyAcquisitionRewardSite": false
        },
        "stateInfo": {
            "requirements": {
                "entitlementUnavailableMessage": ""
            },
        },
        "presentationInfo": {
            "presentationNodeType": 1,
            "parentPresentationNodeHashes": [
                631010939
            ],
            "displayStyle": 3
        },
        "hash": 259147463,
        "index": 2171,
        "redacted": false,
        "blacklisted": false
    },
    "31953747": {
        "displayProperties": {
            "description": "",
            "name": "Ballet Lover",
            "icon": "/common/destiny2_content/icons/c89eb559068c19f8ed62d56a47f33cfa.jpg",
            "hasIcon": true
        },
        "scope": 1,
        "sourceString": "Source: Complete activities and earn rank-up packages on Io.",
        "sourceHash": 315474873,
        "itemHash": 31953747,
        "acquisitionInfo": {
            "runOnlyAcquisitionRewardSite": false
        },
        "stateInfo": {
            "requirements": {
                "entitlementUnavailableMessage": ""
            },
        },
        "presentationInfo": {
            "presentationNodeType": 1,
            "parentPresentationNodeHashes": [
                631010939
            ],
            "displayStyle": 3
        },
        "hash": 259147462,
        "index": 2170,
        "redacted": false,
        "blacklisted": false
    },
    "32806262": {
        "displayProperties": {
            "description": "\"Our mysterious defender slew a Kell today. Kandak has banned other Risen and put a bounty on the so-called Red Moon Phantom's head.\" —Annals of the Saharan Contested Zone",
            "name": "Cloak of Five Full Moons",
            "icon": "/common/destiny2_content/icons/8e0e7dfa87d5c68262b6027cd22efd40.jpg",
            "hasIcon": true
        },
        "scope": 1,
        "sourceString": "Source: Open Legendary engrams and earn faction rank-up packages.",
        "sourceHash": 3334812276,
        "itemHash": 32806262,
        "acquisitionInfo": {
            "runOnlyAcquisitionRewardSite": false
        },
        "stateInfo": {
            "requirements": {
                "entitlementUnavailableMessage": "Requires Destiny 2: Forsaken"
            },
        },
        "presentationInfo": {
            "presentationNodeType": 2,
            "parentPresentationNodeHashes": [
                3988275539
            ],
            "displayStyle": 3
        },
        "hash": 39866533,
        "index": 510,
        "redacted": false,
        "blacklisted": false
    }
}
```

Is anyone able to tell me where I'm going wrong? Is it possible to reference the hash table this way or will I have to store the state hash value in a variable and then reference that variable when making my call to the hash table?

I am using ReactJS.

EDIT:
I'm trying to call the icon path and place it behind a base URL in the renders `img` tag, so I can show the icon of specific items. I have managed to get this working using localStorage and storing the value of the hash but I was wondering if it's possible without using localStorage as the code was incredibly messy and it seemed like a long winded way of doing things, especially when I was having to create localStorage items for many items at a time.

Comment: As `weapon` is the `itemHash` number try `hashdata[{weapon}].displayProperties.icon`